# two sync folders on one laptop?

Tags: sync, directory

Hi can I have a business folder for syncing business files with a remote colleague and a separate personal folder of my own. I don't mind having two accounts. In fact I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's designed for that. However, you might be able to accomplish the same thing by sharing folders. I imagine something like this:

You first create the business and personal accounts. I don't know if this is permitted, so you'll have to check that.

You log into the business account and share a folder with your personal account. Then you log out of that account and into the personal account. You accept the invitation, and then the business account will be synchronized even if the primary account is the personal one. It should work, but I haven't actually tried it. If you do, please provide feedback.